# Loading a shared library implicitly

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-shared-libraries

I would like to integrate a Global library into my build flow. I have written a basic function

**srv/core/jenkins/Checks.groovy:**

```
package core.jenkins

class Checks implements Serializable {
def script

Checks(script) {
    this.script = script
}

def fileExists(){
    script.echo "File exists in the repo."
    }
}
```

And it is exposed as a global var

**vars/fileExisits.groovy:**

```
def call() {
    new core.jenkins.Checks(this).fileExists()
}
```

While configuring the Global Shared Library settings in Jenkins, I have the following settings:

[image]

Now in my jenkinsfile, Im doing something like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'master' }
    stages {
        stage('Check for md files'){
            steps {
                sh 'echo hello'
                script {
                    checks.fileExists()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This always gives the error

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: checks for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at
```

For it to work, I have to add the lines to the top of my Jenkinsfile

```
import core.jenkins.Checks
def checks = new Checks(this)
```

Is there a way for me to invoke the function `fileExists` from a library without having to add the above 2 lines always ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace:

```
checks.fileExists()
```

with:

```
fileExists()
```

All Groovy scripts that implements `def call()` methods and are stored in the `vars/` folder can be triggered by their script file name. Alternatively, if you would like to keep `checks.fileExists()` syntax, then you need to create `vars/checks.groovy` script file and implement `def fileExists()` method inside of it.